# How to use Shader Nodetree in emissions rendering?

Tags: rendering, scripting, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to render my image using a point light source. Now, I want to increase the brightness using node emissions. But, when I do so, I get an error. I have read the related questions here, but my problem is the of a point light source, not sun or material as before. 
Attached are the parameters what I want to change and the error message.

[image].
[image]

I am using this line of code:
    `bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value = 10000`

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

In `bpy.data.node_groups` you will find [node groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/groups.html) that you have made, that is nodes that you have turned into a group that you can use in multiple materials.

The nodes for a light can be found in the lights data property.

```
light_nodes = bpy.data.objects['lamp1'].data.node_tree.nodes
light_nodes['Emission'].inputs['Strength'].default_value = 10000
```